# Swiss visa got rejected

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, switzerland

I applied for a tourist visa for 10 days, submitted all the documents listed on the VFS global site still my visa got rejected stating the reason "your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained".

I wonder why, I submitted my entry ticket to Switzerland and exit from Amsterdam.

Is there a rule that your entry and exit should be from the same country?

I submitted NOC, insurance, bank statements everything

Comment: There is no such rule.  There was something else they didn't like about your application.  For example, they will use that reason if you have no ties to your country of residence (because, although you may have a ticket that you can use to leave the Netherlands, there is no guarantee that you will actually use it).

Comment: @dan1111 for a Schengen visa, the whole letter doesn't tell us much more - it's just a series of check boxes.

Comment: @dan1111 Yes, that would literally be the only statement in the “letter”. British CO write letters full of formulae and sentences to the effect that they are not satisfied of this or that. Except for members of the family of an EU citizen, a Schengen refusal is simply notified using a standard form on which consular officers check one or more boxes and “your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained” is in fact one of the dozen or so valid reasons they have to choose from.

Comment: I will provide more details if the question is reopened but the simple answer is “no, there is no rule like that”. Leaving through another country is completely unproblematic that's the way the Schengen area is supposed to work and a very common occurrence. Furthermore, if there was any problem with your itinerary then the reason for the refusal should be “Justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not provided” or "The information submitted regarding the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable".

Comment: “Your intention to leave the territory of the member state before the expiry of visa could not be ascertained“ suggests something else, namely weak ties to your country of residence (e.g. no evidence of a stable job). It's important to realize that merely submitting all the necessary documentation does not guarantee that you will get a visa. For example, submitting bank statements is unavoidable but the decision depends on what they reveal (do you have a regular income or not, etc.). That's why it might unfortunately not be possible to find a quick solution to your problem.

Comment: Your visa application was rejected because they weren't sufficiently convinced that you would leave Switzerland after ten days. Sure, you have a return ticket, but they think you might not use it.